# I would like to take averages of values in a column depending on values in the cells of another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have large amounts of data relating to an experiment I am performing in a stepwise manner. I would like to take the averages of each step however they are all in the same column so cannot simply take the average of a whole column. Fortunately the data logger I am using can log statuses in another column for each data point.

I was thinking a vba would be able to discern each step from the others by reading the statuses which correspond to each data point (and I can have different statuses for each step: ie Step 1; Step 2; Step 3 etc), then calculate the average and output it in a specific cell.

[this is a simplified version of the type of worksheet I will be looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjhpW.jpg)

I have tried all the average functions in excel itself and I don't think they are suited to what I want them to do. Therefore I assume that I will  have to use either for or if loops in an excel macro, which is fine, but I'm quite new to programming and in particular VBAs and I just don't know where to start!

Comment: You should view [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: `AVERAGEIFS()` didn't work?

Comment: they do, but I would need to change the average if conditions for a ton of worksheets (I think 50+) and I would like to build on the vba to subsequently plot data and do a couple other tasks. Also, if I can have a working VBA, I can leave it to my successors for their theses!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a VBA solution, but I believe a PivotTable can create the averages you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: true, i hadnt thought of that one! I'll have to learn how to plot data from pivot tables, but Im sure I can do that! Any pointers on that one?

Comment: If you create and select a PivotTable it will give you the ability to create a PivotChart based off that data.  You can find the option in the Ribbon at the top.